# Android java How to connect to server with different network/ip address

Tags: java, android, networking, client

How to connect to server with different IP address

I really don't know what to do...

Let me explain first.

i have a client and server that works great when sending messages between the two if i am on the same network as my computer.

i have an android device and i would like to wish when ever i am placed far away and when i will click some button it will send message to server even if i am not on the same network.

Client

```
try {

                client = new Socket("IpAddress", 4444);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                printlng = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                printlng.println(mlng);
                printlng.flush();
                while (true) {
                    if ((Response= in.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.i("Response:", Response);
                        dlng = Double.valueOf(Response);
                        System.out.println(dlng);

                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); // Server socket

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
    }

    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

    while (true) {
        try {

            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get
                                                                    // the
            // client


            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                    clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    bufferedReader.readLine().getBytes(
                            Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String output = bufferedReader2.readLine();
            System.out.println(output.toString());
            out.println(output.toString());
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            inputStreamReader.close();
            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find out the external/internet ip address of the pc where your server is running on. You can do that on that pc with http://whatismyip.com. Use the obtained ip in your client. But before it really can work you have to configure the router where your pc is connected to to forward the used port to the lan ip address of your pc.

Answer (score 0):

If everything works fine when you are on the same LAN : the problem is probably coming from some firewall rule not accepting connection on port 4444 when coming from a non local IP.

So, either change the port of the server (if not used yet, port 80 is probably a good choice since there is more chance that connections will be allowed), either change your firewall rules.

Comment: Well it connects but now i got another problem it says HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Comment: Did you change firewall rules or server port ?

Comment: Wont work..And thanks for replay                                        And also when i am changing back to port 4444 it will work   but if i change back to port 80 it dosent..

Comment: please clarify your problem. What's your problem with the port 4444. Don't hesitate to edit the question.

Comment: I just want to communicate outside of lan with a different network     lets say im on my wifi network(home) and its working but i want if im not at home i want it that it will still connect to server and i will able to communicate.

Comment: ok... but what is the problem. You receive 400 when you are not on the same network ? ("I cannot connect" is a little vague description)

Comment: Yes it is exactly what is happening , im not on the same network and im getting this error.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct server IP (i.e. the IP exposing your server to the outside world ?)

Comment: I got the ip from typing in the cmd command line "ipconfig" and i got in ipv4 the ip address and that is the ip address that i gave to the socket client

Comment: if this address is something like 10.*.*.* or 192.168.*.* this is a local network address, so invisible from outside

Comment: What if I do that between two android phones? Is it gonna work?