# Config IP address to connect Android phone to Python server in different network (using Internet, not local Wifi)

Tags: python, android

I have set up a client (Android phone app, using Android studio) and server (Python, Flask, and/or Socket) system. Everything is OK when I use local IP address (`http://0.0.0.0:8080`, or `http://192.168.3.163:8080`)

But I don't know how to implement the external IP. (My router IP is `http://14.191.81.156:5000`). When I paste this external IP into python code server.py, the cmd alert

1. When I run the code, I received

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

`AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'socket'`

so I changed `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` -> `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)`
and it worked fine with local network.

---

I tried to changed the server's IP code into:

```
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080)),
```

or

```
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5555)),
```

it worked in local network.

If I tried to changed to:

```
s.bind(('14.191.81.156', 8080))
```

OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Or if I changed with '127.0.0.1' address in server side, I received:

```
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
```

OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

---

I want to catch the image from Android phone send to Python server placed in different network, not local Wifi, but cannot using Flask too. I don't know how to get images that server has received.

---

I have seen many post, and I found the most relevance ones here, but still not work. Anything wrong with port 8080, or firewall config
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631176/python-socket-to-connect-over-global-public-ip-address` 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232111/android-java-how-to-connect-to-server-with-different-network-ip-address` 
`https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001201.htm` 
Error: I could not see your service on 14.191.81.156 on port (80) or port (8080) or port (5555)
Reason: Connection timed out

Port 80 is closed on 14.191.81.156.
Port 8080 is closed on 14.191.81.156.
Port 5555 is closed on 14.191.81.156.

How should I do?

Comment: The server does not have to know any ip and you should not bind your server to any ip or if you have to bind you will bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: The client will use the public ip of the router. Now many devices can be connected to your router. But an incoming connection on a port should only be forwarded to one pc. So give your pc a static ip and on the router forward the used port to that ip/pc.

Comment: I think my IP 14.191.81.156 is already a static IP (I have check it on https://www.myip.com/, is it true?). You mean I must set on client side the IP 14.191.81.156:5555 and the server's side number 0.0.0.0:5555?
I'm not clear what to do next. They tell me port 80, 8080, 5555 are closed.

Comment: And I want to catch images which was sent from client to server, too

Comment: `think my IP 14.191.81.156` Your ip? Client, router or pc?

Comment: 14.191.81.156 is the number I received with https://www.myip.com/. My public router IP. The client (android phone) IP and PC server IP now is dynamic, not static.

Comment: The ip of the client is irrelevant. You should forward used port of router to server ip.

Comment: How to "forward used port of router to server ip"?

Comment: You do that in the router settings. Usually using a webinterface. A webserver is build in the router. Pc must have static ip.